# Speeding up Swift CodeFight Challenge

Tags: swift, algorithm

Per Codefighters:

Note: Write a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) additional space complexity, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.

Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.

Example

For a = [2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2], the output should be firstDuplicate(a) = 3.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3 has a smaller index than than second occurrence of 2 does, so the answer is 3.

For a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1], the output should be firstDuplicate(a) = -1.

So here is what I came up with. It works but fails on the final test because it ran over 4000ms. I am stuck to what else I can do. Any Ideas to improve speed?

```
func firstDuplicate(a : [Int]) -> Int {
var duplicateIndexArray = [Int]()
for firstIndex in 0..<a.count {

    for secondIndex in 0..<a.count {

        if a[firstIndex] == a[secondIndex] && firstIndex != secondIndex {
            print(firstIndex, secondIndex)
            if !(duplicateIndexArray.contains(firstIndex)){
                duplicateIndexArray.append(secondIndex)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

// Check for duplicacy
if duplicateIndexArray.count > 0 {
    print(duplicateIndexArray)
    return a[duplicateIndexArray.min()!]
}
return -1
```

}

Comment: Is `a` immutable, or can you reorder values?

Answer (score 0):

The O(n) time part is easy, but the O(1) additional space is a bit tricky. Usually, a hash set (or bit array in your case) can be used to check if a number occurred more than once, but that requires O(n) additional space. For O(1) additional space, we can use the source array itself as a bit array by making some of the numbers in it negative.

For example if the first number in the array is 3, then we make the number at position 3-1 negative. If one of the other numbers in the array is also 3, we can check if the number at position 3-1 is negative.

I don't have any experience with Swift, so I'll try to write a function in [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode):

```
function firstDuplicate(a)
    result = -1

    for i = 0 to a.count - 1
         if a[abs(a[i])-1] < 0 then 
             result = a[i] 
             exit for loop
         else
             a[abs(a[i])-1] = -a[abs(a[i])-1]

    // optional restore the negative numbers back to positive
    for i = 0 to a.count - 1
        if a[i] < 0 then 
            a[i] = -a[i]

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
for secondIndex in 0..<a.count
```

with

```
for secondIndex in firstIndex..<a.count
```

There is no requirement of double checking

So Your Final code is

```
func firstDuplicate(a : [Int]) -> Int {
    var duplicateIndexArray = [Int]()
    for firstIndex in 0..<a.count {

        for secondIndex in firstIndex..<a.count {

            if a[firstIndex] == a[secondIndex] && firstIndex != secondIndex {
                print(firstIndex, secondIndex)
                if !(duplicateIndexArray.contains(firstIndex))
                {
                    duplicateIndexArray.append(secondIndex)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for duplicacy
    if duplicateIndexArray.count > 0
    {
        print(duplicateIndexArray)
        return a[duplicateIndexArray.min()!]
    }
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func firstDuplicate(input: [Int]) -> Int{
    var map : [String : Int] = [:]
    var result = -1
    for i in 0 ..< input.count {
        if map["\(input[i])"] != nil {
            result = i
            break
        }
        else {
            map["\(input[i])"] = i
        }
    }
    return result
}
```